# Travel-specific badges

Tags: discussion, badges

I actually don't know if any other SE sites have this, but hypothetically what bronze, silver and gold badges would you add to Travel.SE if you could?

Bear in mind it'd need to be something ON-SITE, so you can't have a badge for, say, "I went to 5 countries".

Comment: An interesting idea but I suspect the chances of SE implementing it are somewhere between slim and zero. You might be interested in a question I raised on MSE https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344643/is-there-any-policy-reason-why-language-sites-have-badges-named-in-english where some of the responses and comments suggest that the badges are fixed in the UI.

Comment: @mdewey interesting re the translations! Arguably that could be done for the Christmas hats as well

Answer (score 10):

I'd like bronze, silver and  gold "World traveller" badges for:

- asking at least one upvoted question in 1, 3 and 10 country-specific tags
- answering (with at least 1 upvote) in 1, 10 and 20 country-specific badges.

Bronze, silver and gold "Lost treasure" badges for:

- answering 3 questions with no upvoted answer after 3 months, 6 months and 12 months.